# JasperReports taking no notice of year in SQL BETWEEN function

Tags: sql, type-conversion

So im trying to query a database between 2 dates for a JasperReport

This code :

```
<![CDATA[SELECT * FROM OPTimeEntry WHERE Date >= '01/01/2015' AND Date <= '31/12/2012']]>
```

Gives the same result as :

```
<![CDATA[SELECT * FROM OPTimeEntry WHERE Date >= '01/01/1111' AND Date <= '31/12/1111']]>
```

and This :

```
<![CDATA[SELECT * FROM OPTimeEntry WHERE Date >= '01/01/AAAA' AND Date <= '31/12/AAAA']]>
```

Why does it take no notice of the year and just returns all results for 2014 in between the day and year?

Edit - It takes no note of the month either.

Comment: Store dates in the database using the correct format -- dates/datetime -- and not as strings, and your code will work.

Comment: Sorry new to Java here but what is the correct format. Do you mean as a Date object rather than String?

Comment: Hi I understand what you mean now. Save it as a date object and use format yyyy-dd-mm. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date is stored as String in Database when it should be stored as a Date Object.

Format should also be yyyy-mm-dd.

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff